# Rails render mail_form gem from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

From travels, which belongs to offer, I'm trying to render a form generated with the mail_form gem.
But I get an error with this message:
*undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class*

**travels/show**

```
= render :partial => '/question_forms/form', :question_form => @question_form
```

Any hint how to get this?  I've tried including the question_form model as an association to travel, but it doesn't work.

This is the question_forms_controller default code:

```
class QuestionFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question_form = QuestionForm.new
  end

  def create
    begin
        @question_form = QuestionForm.new(params[:question_form])
        @question_form.request = request
        if @question_form.deliver
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
        else
          render :new
        end
      rescue ScriptError
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry, this message appears to be spam and was not delivered.'
      end
  end

end
```

In my travels_controller I tried to load @question_form using the same method, but this doesn't seem the way:

```
 def new
    @offer_season = OfferSeason.find(params[:offer_season_id])
    @travel = @offer_season.travels.find(params[:id])

    @question_form =  @travel.questionforms.new
  end

  def create
    @offer_season = OfferSeason.find(params[:offer_season_id])
    @travel = @offer_season.travels.find(params[:id])


    begin
        @question_form = @travel.questionforms.new(params[:question_form])
        @question_form.request = request
        if @question_form.deliver
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
        else
          render :new
        end
      rescue ScriptError
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry, this message appears to be spam and was not delivered.'
      end
  end
```

Comment: What is the backtrace of the error and what does the question_forms/forms partial look like?

Comment: The error is undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class, the
question_forms/forms is a basic form: - form_for @question_form do |f|

Comment: The error you're referring to is common when the object passed to the `form_for` (in this case, `@question_form`) is nil. Without seeing the backtrace and the context of the form, I'm mostly guessing.

Comment: It looks like your @question_form on new method isn't referencing a "QuestionsForm" object. Stick with "@question_form = QuestionForm.new" and it should work..